# Accessing list of Google search engines using API client for PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-custom-search

I am using Google's [API client for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started), which works fine getting search results. But what I want to do is get a list of the custom search engines in my account. I have this code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google CustomSearch PHP Application');
$client->setDeveloperKey('[key]');
$client->setClientId('[client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('[client_secret]');
$search = new Google_Service_Customsearch($client);
```

Then if I want to do a search, for example, this produces results:

```
$result = $search->cse->listCse('test', array('cx' => '[cse_id]'));
```

So I know it's working. But I want to be able to make the call that retrieves the list of CSEs, following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api#retrieve_list):

> An account can have more than one search engine. To retrieve the
>   complete list of custom search engines for the account, send an
>   authenticated GET request to the following URL:
>
> http://cse.google.com/api/[USER_ID]/cse/[CSE_ID]

The problem is that I don't know how to translate this call into the syntax for Google's API client for PHP.

Comment: Another problem is that the docs can't be right in this case -- why would you pass a `cse_id` to an endpoint whose role is to return a list of CSEs?

Comment: As far I understand, we can't make call like that at the moment ([Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api#authenticating)), except if we already have some old auth token. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/customsearch/Y__R8JVfwFM/r74zccztCAAJ

Comment: Yes, client login [is no longer available](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) but I thought that since the PHP client allowed other methods this one would also be supported.

Comment: related question- no solution yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599957/oauth2-scope-for-google-custom-search-api

Comment: for Site Search customers (paid search engines) there is an XML solution, another solution is described here too https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, but that second link is not a solution to this problem (at least the non-paid version).

Comment: Anyone figure this out yet?