# How to perform a Google custom search in Haskell (with gogol)?

Tags: haskell, google-custom-search

I'm trying to perform a Google custom search with Gogol. I have the following code, but it doesn't compile and I don't understand the error message that tells me why. How do I get the program to compile so that the google search works?

```
searchCoversCustomly :: Text -> IO Search
searchCoversCustomly phrase = do
    env   <- G.newEnv  -- create google environment
    rVols <- G.runResourceT . G.runGoogle env $ do  -- run request
        let request =   (cSEList phrase)            -- request construction
                      & (cselCx .~ Just cx)
                      . (cselNum .~ 3)
                      . (cselSearchType .~ Just Image)
        G.send request
    return rVols
  where cx  = "..."
```

This results in the following error message:

```
src/GoogleInteraction.hs:56:12: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘s0’ arising from a use of ‘G.newEnv’
      prevents the constraint ‘(G.AllowScopes s0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘s0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance G.AllowScopes '[]
          -- Defined in ‘Network.Google.Auth.Scope’
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: env <- G.newEnv
      In the expression:
        do { env <- G.newEnv;
             rVols <- G.runResourceT . G.runGoogle env
                      $ do { let ...;
                             G.send request };
             return rVols }
```

I have a working snippet of code for Google Books also working with Gogol. The difference is that I provide a relevant scope there, as the Gogol docs [instruct](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.1.1/docs/Network-Google.html).

For Books that BooksScope as documented in [gogol-books' docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-books-0.2.0/docs/Network-Google-Books-Types.html), but there is no such scope mentioned in gogol-customsearch's docs.

How do I get the program to compile so that the google search works? Thanks!

=== Edit: including the error message after changing to `G.newEnv <$> forbid` ===

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
                  with actual type ‘k10 '[] -> k10 '[]’
    • Probable cause: ‘G.forbid’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘G.forbid’
```

Comment: The type variable that it complains about represents the 'credentials' (whatever that is.. I know nothing about the google API). You need to specify the type somewhere, perhaps with `env :: Env Something <- ...`. I don't know what `Something` should be but I would assume you are aware of which 'credentials' you intend to use. Alternatively, use `newEnvWith` which allows you to specify the [credentials](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.1.1/docs/Network-Google-Auth.html#t:Credentials) on the value level.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. If I understand Google Custom Search correctly, then you authenticate with a key=... keyvalue-pair appended to the URL.

I don't see a Key type in the linked credentials docs, so maybe it's not possible to do it this way?

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that the type checker can't figure out which instance of `AllowScopes` to use because you didn't specify the scope. I will have to speculate on what to do about that, given that I know very little about the specifics of the custom search API.

Assuming that there is no OAuth2 scope for custom search -- which seems to be the case, given the absence of predefined scopes in *gogol-customsearch* (as you noted), as well as the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599957/oauth2-scope-for-google-custom-search-api) -- you can use [`forbid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.1.1/docs/Network-Google-Auth-Scope.html#v:forbid) from `Network.Google.Auth.Scopes` to "annotate credentials with no scope authorization".

```
searchCoversCustomly phrase = do
    env <- G.newEnv <&> G.forbid
    -- etc.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining the error message and suggesting a fix.

I think it's correct that there's no OAuth2 scope then, because google's custom search works with an appended key=... keyvalue-pair to authenticate a request.

Could you maybe explain the type of `forbid?` It's `k '[] -> k '[]`, but I don't understand it. It's like `id`, but with lenses and lists? How can there be no type in the list (like `[a] -> [a]`)?

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I ask because I don't know what I should pass along to forbid

Comment: @Arthur [1/2] `'[]` -- note the `'` -- is a *type-level* list; more specifically, it is an empty list being used as a type annotation. `forbid` is indeed a specialised `id`; its only purpose is ensuring the scope type annotation is `'[]`. Similarly, all `envScopes .~ booksScope` does is setting the scope type parameter to the type-level list `'["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books"]`, just like `allow booksScope` would do. (The extra thing `envScopes` makes possible is that, being a lens, it can be used to conveniently retrieve the scope from the environment, through the means of a `Proxy`.)

Comment: @Arthur [2/2] That's to say, you do not need to pass anything else to `forbid`. `newEnv <&> forbid` should just work, at least as far as the typechecker is concerned.

Comment: Aha, aha. That clears up the types, thanks. Strangely enough, the compiler does ask for an extra argument. I'll include the error in the original post. I guess I need to make k10 (see top post) explicit. No idea what it could be though.